# Visual studio flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart

I'm kind of new to flutter, and I'm initiating VS studio as my IDE, I'm trying to search for the Flutter and Dart plugins to download but for some reason I can't find them on visual studio. (I'm following FreeCodeCamp course for flutter as reference )

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are different IDE's, so make sure you are adding the code part.

In the extension menu, search flutter, and it's the first one.

Make sure you have VS Code and not VS. The icon for VS Code is blue while VS is purple.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the user uses VS Code, make sure you are using VS code to get the Flutter extension and Visual Studio.

Follow this link to download VScode: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

And here are some extension which we normally use

Name: **Flutter** 
Id: Dart-Code.flutter 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

Name: **GitLens — Git supercharged** 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens

Name: **Material Icon Theme** 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme

Name: **Live Share** 
Publisher: Microsoft 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare

Name: **Material Theme** 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme

Name: **YAML** 
Publisher: Red Hat 
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml

will keep updating this list if possible.